# Accessing ui element in other thread wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need to access `TextBoxes` in my `WPF` application from another thread and I've got an exception. I know, there is a property `Dispatcher` in every UI control and a method `BeginInvoke` , but I don't know how to get values from `TextBoxes`.

So, here is the code:

```cs
private void TestConnection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var task = new Task(() => TryConnect());
                task.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message); 
            }
        }
        void TryConnect()
        {
            try
            {
                string con_str = "Server=" + Ip.Text + ";Port=" + Port.Text +
                ";Database=hospital;Uid=" + login.Text + 
                ";Pwd=" + password.Text + ";";
                using (MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(con_str))
                {
                    mcon.Open();
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection is OK!");
                    mcon.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ErrorCode.ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bescause my app has GUI and that is why the user should be able to pass to my app whatever he/she wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a copy of the values you need, then you should be able to access them:

```
string username = login.Text, password = password.Text, ip = Ip.Text, port = Port.Text;
var task = new Task(() => TryConnect(username, password, ip, port));
```

And:

```
void TryConnect(string username, string password, string ip, string port) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Copying the values locally like this means you don't need to access UI elements from your background thread.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, move the connection string build out of the task action:

```
        private void TestConnection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string con_str = "Server=" + Ip.Text + ";Port=" + Port.Text + ";Database=hospital;Uid=" + login.Text + ";Pwd=" + password.Text + ";";

            var task = new Task(() => TryConnect(con_str));
            task.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
    void TryConnect(string con_str)
    {
        try
        {

            using (MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection(con_str))
            {
                mcon.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connection is OK!");
                mcon.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ErrorCode.ToString() + " " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

But you have a lot of issues in this code.

- Code behind in WPF is not "Best practice"
  Try and have a look at this:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx
- MessageBox on another thread can cause a lot of pain.
- you are trying to catch an exception around the task creation, this will not catch exceptions thrown inside the action.
  Try this instead:

  ```
      private void TestConnection_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      string con_str = "Server=" + Ip.Text + ";Port=" + Port.Text + ";Database=hospital;Uid=" + login.Text + ";Pwd=" + password.Text + ";";
      var dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
      var task = new Task(() => TryConnect(con_str));
      task.ContinueWith(task1 =>
          {
              //TODO Handle exception
              System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(task1.Exception);
              //or if you really want an messageBox, pass it back to the ui thread
              dispatcher.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show(task1.Exception.Message));

          }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
      task.Start();
  }
  ```